# Media.play not working synchronously in Android 4.3

Tags: android, synchronization, android-mediaplayer

I'm creating a smartphone app that is essentially a talking phrasebook, using App Framework 2 and Cordova 2.9, testing on a Samsung Galaxy S4. I found that after playing about 25 - 30 sound clips the sound stopped playing. I found the problem was that audio resources on Android are finite and not being released after issuing the media.play. I added a console log for each successful play and this showed successful execution even when it ran out of resources.

So, I added media.stop and media.release after the media.play (as discussed in several other questions on this forum and elsewhere) and found sound stopped working completely....sigh.

On a hunch, I added an alert statement between the media.play and media.stop and now sounds can be played as often as I want so long as I click OK when the alert displays. I also noticed the console log entries were no longer being made at all. So, it looks like the command after media.play is being executed immediately and not waiting for the sound to finish playing. Thus I issue media.play and before it can play the media.stop and media.release are executed and so I'm getting no sound. This seems to be confirmed as I noticed the alert was being displayed before the sound clip had finished playing and tapping OK terminated the sound playback, presumably because the media.stop and media.release were executed.

Am I misunderstanding how a synchronous call is supposed to work? Any suggestions to fix this much appreciated. Here's my js code:

```
    <!-- Get the web root path -->
<script type="text/javascript">
 function getWebRoot() {
    "use strict" ;
    var path = window.location.href ;
    path = path.substring( 0, path.lastIndexOf( '/' ) ) ;
    return path ;
}
</script>
<!-- /Get the web root path -->

<!-- Play sound using cordova -->
<script type="text/javascript">
function soundclip() {
   var my_media = new Media(getWebRoot() + "/test.ogg",  function() { console.log("my media found so stop and release after play"); }); 
my_media.play() ;
if (my_media) {
    alert("my media found alert before stop and release") ;
    my_media.stop();
    my_media.release();
        } ; // End If my_media
      } ; // End soundclip
</script>
<!-- /Play sound using cordova -->
```

And here's the html

```
<input type="button"  onClick="soundclip()" value=" Play Ay Caramba 1">
```

Thanks for any suggestions, this is driving me nuts !!

Comment: I fixed it. The problem is that

Comment: I fixed it. The problem is that media.play does not wait to finish playing before the media.stop and media.release are executed. So my_media.play() ;
my_media.stop();
my_media.release();  does not work, at least not on a Samsung GS4 with Android 4.3. So I did this and it works perfectly<script type="text/javascript">
function soundclip() {
 var my_media = new Media(getWebRoot() + "/test.ogg", 
 function() { my_media.stop(); my_media.release();},
 function() { my_media.stop(); my_media.release();}); 
my_media.play() ;
      } ; // End soundclip
</script>